# Getting HTML Parent Window Won't Work. Suggestions?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two HTML Documents:

### Main.html

```
<html lang="eng">
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var ExamId = "001A";

    function open_exam()
    {
      window.open("exam.html")
    }
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <input type=button value="Open Exam" onclick="open_exam()">
  </body>
</html>
```

### Exam.html

```
<html lang="eng">
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setParentInfo()
    {
        window.parent.document.ExamID = '001B';
    }
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome to the Exam!</p>
    <input type=button value="Set Parent Info" onclick="setParentInfo()">
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Main.html brings up Exam.html via the input button.  From inside Exam.html I would like to change the variable ExamID on the parent document (i.e.: Main.html).  I'm trying to do this via the JavaScript function:  setParentInfo().

The above code is not working.  Can someone help me come up with the correct code?

Thanks So Much!

Comment: I changed the variable to EXAMID in both Main.html and Exam.html so that there will not be a problem with case sensitivity.  When I run it I get "undefined" when it tries to execute:  onclick="setParentInfo()"  Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Your code works perfectly well in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Variables are assigned on the `window` object, not the `document` object.

Since the value is already set, you can instead read the existing value to verify it:

```
alert(window.parent.ExamId); // == "001A"
```

Comment: I didn't.  Your statement was true that after the script execution in the child, document.ExamID was set but in the parent they had set var ExamId, which became window.ExamId which was accessible as window.parent.ExamId in the child.  They were setting an entirely new variable which is why they didn't see a change.

Answer (score 0):

Variable is declared and assigned in parent window so you get reference from your child window.

you can test using `alert` statement:

```
alert(window.parent.document.ExamId);

//output::001B
```